# Java: Comparing two lists, if either contains the value of the other, add all values of both to a new list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap, hashset

I have a HashMap with String keys and ArrayList of MyObject values and now I want to make a new list of lists which contain all overlapping MyObjects.

For example: if ArrayList1 contains MyObjectA, MyObjectB, MyObjectC and ArrayList2 contains MyObjectA, MyObjectD, MyObjectE, then I want to add MyObjectA - E to a new list and put all of these lists in a master list. I want to essentially combine all of each ArrayList's values into a new list if any of the values overlap.

So far I'm just iterating through the map, and over each list, then nesting an iteration again, and if any value matches, doing another iteration of both ArrayLists in the nest to add them to a different list, but this is leading to duplication within the new list of lists.

Sorry if this isn't very clear.

Does anyone have any suggestions or perhaps a better way to accomplish this?

Thank You!

Here's my code:

```
public class DetermineOverlaps {

HashMap<String, ArrayList<CustomObject>> pgsPerStMap;

HashSet<HashSet<String>> competingPgs;

public DetermineOverlaps (HashMap<String, ArrayList<CustomObject>> pgsPerStMap2){

    pgsPerStMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<CustomObject>>(pgsPerStMap2);

    competingPgs = calculateCompetingPgs();

}

public HashSet<HashSet<String>> calculateCompetingPgs (){

    //This will be the hashset which gets returned from this method
    HashSet<HashSet<String>> competingProdGros = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();

    //I will iterate over each term (key) within the pgsPerStMap map, which contains search terms | all customObject for that search term
    for (String searchTerm : pgsPerStMap.keySet()){

        //I will iterate over each customObject for the search term
        ArrayList<CustomObject> searchTermsPgs = pgsPerStMap.get(searchTerm);

        for (CustomObject curProdGroup : searchTermsPgs){

            String curProdGroupName = curProdGroup.key;

            //I will store all found matches in this hashset, which I will later put in the competingProdGros map
            HashSet<String> tempPgSet = new HashSet<String>();

            //Compare every other key/value combination of the map to every other key/value combination of the map
            for (String searchTerm2ndLevel : pgsPerStMap.keySet()){
                //Iterate over the customObject
                ArrayList<CustomObject> searchTermsPgsLev2 = pgsPerStMap.get(searchTerm2ndLevel);

                for (CustomObject curProdGroup2ndLevel : searchTermsPgsLev2){

                     String curProdGroupLevel2Name = curProdGroup2ndLevel.key;
                    //If these are different keys, but the same value, i.e. you've got a value which has multiple
                    //overlapping keys, and the temporary hashset doesn't contain the value already
                    //Then add all values from both arraylist<CustomObject> into the temporary hashset...
                    if (!searchTerm2ndLevel.equals(searchTerm) && curProdGroupLevel2Name.equals(curProdGroupName)
                    && !tempPgSet.contains(curProdGroupLevel2Name)){

                        for (CustomObject levelOnePg : searchTermsPgs){

                            String levelOnePgKey = levelOnePg.key;

                            tempPgSet.add(levelOnePgKey);

                        }

                        for (CustomObject levelTwoPg : searchTermsPgsLev2){

                            String levelTwoPgKey = levelTwoPg.key;
                            tempPgSet.add(levelTwoPgKey);

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            //Add the temporary hashset into the competingProdGros hashset
            if(!competingProdGros.contains(tempPgSet)){competingProdGros.add(tempPgSet);}

        }

    }

    //return the competingprodgros hashset
    return competingProdGros;

}
```

Comment: I think [**CODE REVIEW**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for this question.

Comment: I recommend learning about the `addAll` (union) and `retainAll` (intersection) methods of the `List` interface.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make heads or tails of what it is you're trying to do, but I can give you some ideas to help you implement it.

You said you want a list of objects A-E, so I would say you are not allowing for duplicates. In which case you could use a map of String to Sets instead to cut down on the size of your master list

I'm going to give you 4 scenarios:

Scenario 1: you do not allow for duplicates and lists are references to the objects with unique contents

```
Map<String, Set<MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, Set<MyObject>>();
Set<MyObject> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<MyObject>();
Set<MyObject> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<MyObject>();
MyObject a = new MyObject("A");
MyObject b = new MyObject("B");
MyObject c = new MyObject("C");
MyObject d = new MyObject("D");
MyObject e = new MyObject("E");
set1.add(a);
set1.add(b);
set1.add(c);
set2.add(c);
set2.add(d);
set2.add(e);
set2.removeAll(set1)
set1.addAll(set2);
map.put("Mykey", set1);
```

What this says is the objects are the same among the sets and thus will be removed between the two sets. The contents of set1 are:

```
[ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ]
```

Scenario 2: You do allow for duplicates and lists are references to the same objects. Here I'm guessing you would want a 1-to-1 removal, so something you loop through a set of intersections until is empty then add the list to the combined list. If you need to maintain the values of your list, you can always instantiate a new one and pass it the contents of your list

A couple last notes: removing the element of a tree set in an enhanced for loop risks throwing a ConcurrentModificationException

```
MyObject a = new MyObject("A");
MyObject b = new MyObject("B");
MyObject c = new MyObject("C");
MyObject d = new MyObject("D");
MyObject e = new MyObject("E");
List<CodeTester> l = new ArrayList<CodeTester>();
List<CodeTester> l2 = new ArrayList<CodeTester>();
l.add(a);
l.add(c);
l.add(c);
l.add(b);
l.add(b);
l.add(d);
l2.add(c);
l2.add(d);
l2.add(d);
l2.add(e);
Set<CodeTester> set = new HashSet<CodeTester>(l);
set.retainAll(l2); // get the intersections
while(!set.isEmpty()) {
    l2.remove(0);
    set.retainAll(l2);
}
map.put("myKey", set);
```

The output of these contents is:

```
[ "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "D", "D", "E" ]
```

Notice that 1 instance of "C" and "D" were excluded from the final list because the other list had them

Scenario 3: You do not allow for duplicates but list elements are not guaranteed to be references to objects with unique contents

If I had to guess I'd say this is the one you're looking for. 
Here MyObject instantiates new instances with different hash codes/ids. This makes all MyObject instances unique regardless of contents, so if you declare two MyObjects with the same String, they will not be removed/retained by default Collections operations. To compare contents, you'll need to implement a few a few overridden methods. Then you'll be able to use the above procedures the same way. Only difference is to user TreeSet instead of HashSet to invoke the overridden equals method then we can either implement Comparable or implement a Comparator to use the TreeSet and avoid the ClassCastException it would throw from its default Comparator.

For Sets to enforce uniqueness:

```
public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject>
String s;
Map<String, Set<MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, Set<MyObject>>();
Map<String, List<MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, List<MyObject>>();

public MyObject(String s){
    this.s = s;
}

public void myExample1(){
    Set<MyObject> set1 = new TreeSet<MyObject>();
    Set<MyObject> set2 = new TreeSet<MyObject>();
    MyObject a = new MyObject("A");
    MyObject b = new MyObject("B");
    MyObject c = new MyObject("C");
    MyObject d = new MyObject("D");
    MyObject e = new MyObject("E");
    MyObject b2 = new MyObject(new StringBuilder("F").replace(0, 1, "B").toString());
    MyObject d2 = new MyObject(new StringBuilder("G").replace(0, 1, "D").toString());
    set1.add(a);
    set1.add(b);
    set1.add(c);
    set2.add(b2);
    set2.add(d);
    set2.add(d2);
    set2.add(e);
    set2.removeAll(set1)
    set1.addAll(set2);
    mapS.put("Mykey", set1);
}

public void myExample2(){
    List<MyObject> l = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    List<MyObject> l2 = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    l.add(a);
    l.add(c);
    l.add(c);
    l.add(b2);
    l.add(d);
    l2.add(b);
    l2.add(d);
    l2.add(d2);
    l2.add(e);
    Set<MyObject> set = new TreeSet<MyObject>(l);
    set.retainAll(l2); // get the intersections
    Set<MyObject> set2 = new HashSet<MyObject>(set);
    while(!set.isEmpty()) {
        l2.remove(0);
        set.retainAll(l2);
    }
    l.addAll(l2);
    mapL.put("myKey", l);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(MyObject o){
    return s.compareTo(o.getS);
}

public String getS(){
    return s;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    return o instanceof MyObject && compareTo((MyObject) o);
}
```

}

myExample1 Outputs:

```
[ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ]
```

With has codes to show uniqueness:

```
[A 865113938, B 1442407170, C 1028566121] [B 1118140819, D 1975012498, E 1808253012]
[A 865113938, B 1442407170, C 1028566121, D 1975012498, E 1808253012]
```

myExample1 Outputs:

```
[ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ]
```

With hash codes to show uniqueness:

```
[A 865113938, C 1442407170, C 1442407170, B 1028566121, D 1118140819] [B 1975012498, D 1118140819, D 1808253012, E 589431969]
[A 865113938, C 1442407170, C 1442407170, B 1028566121, D 1118140819, E 589431969]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addAll() function.
eg: ArrayList1.addAll(ArrayList2) 
Now ArrayList1 will contain all values without duplicates

Comment: I feel the answer is more complicated than that. OP's using an ArrayList so maybe he wants to allow for duplicates?

At any rate addAll called by a list will not resolve duplicates or intersections, so this answer is just wrong